# How do deal with hierarchical notes?

Tags: org-mode, org-roam

I like to keep notes for all my contacts, but also want to avoid "namespace pollution" when using `org-roam-node-find`. If I have 500 contacts I would rather they all live under a contacts namespace, example `contacts.John Doe`, where John Doe will not appear in search results unless `contacts.` is first entered.

[Dendroam](https://github.com/greghab/dendroam) is one attempt to solve this problem, but it appears to be broken and unmaintained. (this error: "Blocking call to accept-process-output with quit inhibited!!").

Am I thinking about this in the right way? Are there other approaches that I should consider to get the same or similar result?

Comment: I think roam is just not the right tool. Org mode has a contact management plugin as part of org-plus-contrib. Then to search for contacts, simply search within that file. You can still add links to and from roam notes to contacts if desired.

Comment: Contacts was just an example. I have several kinds of hierarchies that fit this use case.